# Zend Framework - Can you support multiple View Renderers?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend Framework project that because of the expertise of previous programmers, used the view Smarty view rendering engine (set up in the bootstrapper).

I'd now like to - over time - migrate to either the default ZF PHTML view renderer or maybe even use [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org/).

Can ZF (version 1.10+) support multiple view renderers while I make the migration (.tpl to .phtml)? I can't find any documentation on the subject.

Comment: Is the view manually instantiated in each action, or are you relying on magic?  It also depends on how they wedged Smarty in there.  A while ago, it was accepted practice to simply write a wrapper around Smarty that implemented `Zend_View_Abstract`...

Comment: Thanks Charles, the implementation is by extending `Zend_View_Abstract` then setting this in the bootstrapper e.g.

`$view = new My_View_Smarty($config->smarty->toArray()); // extends Zend_View_Abstract`
`$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');`
`$viewRenderer->setView($view);`
$viewRenderer->setViewSuffix($config->smarty->suffix);`

Comment: Okay, so in this case, you *should* be able to just declare a replacement View on a case by case basis for each action you want to modernize.  Unfortunately I don't immediately recall how to properly do this, but it should open the door for an answer from someone else that knows how.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi 
i use of default zend framework view but i can use of smarty view in it 
with this code

`echo $this->render("sample.tpl");`

i`m sure u can do this too but u must write a code like this in view file

```
echo $this->render("sample.phtml");
```

or like this in controller file

```
$this->view->render("sample.phtml");
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Set any new layout as follows.

```
$this->layout()->setLayout('layout1'); // layout.phtml
```

If you have multiple layouts you can use this conditionally.

Disable a layout as follows

```
$this->layout()->disableLayout();
```

In your layout template do the following to render multiple templates.

```
<?php echo $this->render('header.phtml') ?>
<?php echo $this->render('sidebar.phtml') ?>
<?php echo $this->render('box.phtml') ?>
<?php echo $this->render('slider.phtml') ?>
```